# VelocityJS(velocity-animate) + WebPack - How can I use it?

Tags: javascript, webpack, velocity.js

I have started using Webpack and I have installed VelocityJS(velocity-animate) from NPM.

I am importing it like this

```
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
```

but I don't really know how to use it.

For example ... How would I write this?

```
$('.secondary-content').velocity({translateX: '0%'});
```

I have tried this but it did not work.

`Velocity.$('.secondary-content').velocity({translateX: '0%'})`

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: @AguV I  found a solution long time ago but it required jQuery, do you want me to write it as an answer?

Comment: I've found that solution as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
Velocity(toAnim, { opacity: 0.05 }, 1000);
```

Quelle:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/animating-without-jquery/

My tested platform: 
+ webpack@2.2.0
+ webpack-dev-server@2.2.0
+ babel-core@6.22.1
+ babel-loader@7.2.10
+ babel-preset-es2015@6.22.0

cheers! :D

Answer (score 1):

I've use this and worked for me:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
require('velocity-animate');
delete window.jQuery;
delete window.$;
```